# Setting multiple unique constraints

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to set unique contraints for multiple columns in the database for my WordPress plugin. I have seen many answers to similar questions here on Stack, but I'm unable to make it work in my context. I followed the WordPress documentation for [Creating Tables with Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).

I have tried

```
CREATE TABLE media (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name tinytext NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mediaID UNIQUE (id, email)
) $charset_collate;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE media (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;
ALTER TABLE media
    ADD UNIQUE (email)
```

Unfortunately non of these works, as I'm able to add two records with same email address. I have tried to enter "ALTER TABLE..." manually into phpMyAdmin, and then it works. But not in the plugin code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "none of the work"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mureinik No error, but I'm able to add two records with same email address.

Comment: Even with the second DDL?

Comment: @Mureinik Yes, when I use it in my code. But the "ALTER TABLE.." works if I do the query in phpMyAdmin after the code creates the table.

Comment: run a `show create table media ` and paste the output

Comment: @Dan Seems I got the exact same as the `CREATE` I'm using (now the first one).